# Sending A post request from ajax to a python function but receiving a GET request?

Tags: ajax, django, post, get

I am new to Django.I am sending a ajax POST request to a python function which in turn stores the data in the variables from the ajax and return the HttpResponse .So i checked request.method in python its coming as GET.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"create_post/",
  type:"POST",

  data : {F_Name: First_Name ,L_Name: Last_name,Eadd: Email , Password: Pass},
  success:function(){
    window.location.href="create_post/";
    console.log ("Success")
  },
  cache:false,
  failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

this is my ajax request.

its sending the data to this function .

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        First_name=request.GET['F_Name'];
        Last_Name=request.GET["L_Name"];
        Email_address=request.GET["Eadd"];
        Pass=request.GET["Password"];
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>hi this is me .</body></html>");
```

When I checked as `return(request.method)` its giving me `GET`.

Can some one explain this behavior?
And in the function i have `request.method==GET` in this scenario DJango is giving me internal server 500 error.

Thanks

Comment: I am still getting the same GET request , I replaced `type` with `method`

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, are you sure it's sending a GET request? Can you show your URL config?

Comment: in the views.py i checked it... 
`def create_post(request): return HttpResponse(request.method) `

I am getting GET.So that means its a GET request ?

Comment: Check in your browser developer option whether the request triggered is sent as POST or GET (on browser side).

Comment: you can `print request.method` and look at your console to see if it prints POST or GET

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised to see that none of you didn't noticed that he has define method: "POST" in his ajax and his function is used on "GET" request.

And the main reason he is getting the output for print request.method = "GET" and 500 error is because of using window.location.href="create_post/" in his ajax success function. Every request is by default a get request unless we explicitly define it "POST" or any other.

So here it goes like this,
- Ajax calls the url via POST, for unknown reason the response comes in success function(weird coz according to the view posted POST method return nothing to ajax request).
- The success function again calls the same url(page refresh) via a GET request and he sees print request.method as "GET" with 500 error coz this is wrong way to do so.

Comment: I am sorry for that i had no clues how to approach web , when i was learning the Django .But thanks a ton for noticing .

Answer (score -1):

your ajax method is post, so i think your views.py may try this

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        First_name=request.POST['F_Name']
        Last_Name=request.POST["L_Name"]
        Email_address=request.POST["Eadd"]
        Pass=request.POST["Password"]
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>hi this is me .</body></html>")
```

Comment: in the views.py  i checked it...
            `def create_post(request):
                    return HttpResponse(request.method)`


I am getting GET.So that means its a GET request ?